# To expand variables in string for PHP from a MySQL query result

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is a tiny version of it.

My MySQL table "reports" look like this:

```
reports

rep_id     rep_description       rep_query
varchar 3      varchar 50        varchar 50
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| R01   | Name search      |  SELECT name FROM customers  WHERE name='$var'  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| R02   | All names        |  SELECT name FROM customers                     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One report_list.php generates a list of available reports.
If the report have a "search field", it is placed in a html form.
For the R01 we will have this:

```
<h3>R01</h3>`
<form action="generator.php" method=post>
<input type="text" name="var" >Search String
<input type="hidden" name="rep" value='R01'>
<input type="submit"></form>
```

This is the "generator.php". Have in mind that all MySQL injections and code protection has been placed. **The kernel of the problem is just the string expansion**.

```
<?php
$var=$_REQUEST['var'];
$rep=$_REQUEST['rep'];

mysql_connect(******,*****,******,false,65536);
@mysql_select_db(*******) or die("Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT rep_query FROM reports WHERE rep_id='$rep'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$runsql=mysql_result($result,0,'rep_query');

//Now run the query you just got from querying the MySQL

$runthatquery=mysql_query($runsql);
// Here it should run "SELECT name FROM customers  WHERE name='$var'"
.
.
// I removed the code that print the query results
?>
```

The problem is that $runsql **WILL RUN** "SELECT name FROM customers" from R02.
And it **WILL NOT RUN** "SELECT name FROM customers  WHERE name='$var'" - Because $var is not expanded.

I know it is possible to use a function with substr, replace (and so on) to change the string once it is retrieved from MySQL. **I dont want to do that** because my real life code has a lot of variables.

I've tried eval and parse_str (just to try out) without success.

Hence, my question is: Is there a command to convert this string into a string with proper expanding of the variables?

Comment: clearly not the code your using as its full of syntax errors. paste  the *exact* code, cant debug an approximation.

Comment: $runsql=mysql_result$result,0,sqlquery); missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Why are you storing SQL queries in the database?! SQLception?

Comment: Sorry for the code sintax. I wrote it in a rush. But you got the spirit.

Comment: If you want me to take time to read and answer your question, return the favour and take time when asking.

Comment: My apologies Dagon. The thing is pretty simple, I can't expand the variables from a SQL string. I don't know if it is possible. And all searches I've done did not show a similar problem.

Comment: I cleared the question. I think is ok now.

Answer (score 3):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP works, and storing raw PHP variable names in your database records is the WRONG way to go about this. If you *HAVE* to store queries like that, then store proper prepared-statement-style queries, e.g.

```
SELECT name WHERE name = :name
```

then use a proper DB interface library like mysqli or PDO to fill in those placeholders.

Comment: I have a report generator. The "list" of the reports contain the name of the reports, queries, type, etc is hold in a MySQL table. My wish was to have the reports hold the maximum information for a single php "generator". If I have the SQL of each report on it, I wont need to have a file for each one.